# JQuery AJAX JSF / jsf tags are not identified. Cannot find FacesContext

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf

I am facing a problem while using jquery ajax and jsf combination. I am not pretty sure if this is a usual problem and can be handled, but hoping to get a solution.

here is the scenario. we are developing a portal project with jsf. so on a page we have to load huge data in terms of rows in a table(appx 300-400 sometimes) and each row will have a Link which needs to open a popup. so in order not to hit the performance of the page, i am planning to lazy load the jsp(popup content). so thought to go for ajax. the jsp is having the jsf tags which are not recognizing by the ajax load. I understand when the jsp loads by ajax it will be a plain/independent (un jsf'tified) version.

so my question is : how can i make the jsp(popup content) in this scenario jsf'tified so that jsf tags can be visible.

currently i am getting cannot find FacesContext.

i am using the following code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "text/html; charset=ISP-8859-1" ,
    url: '<%=renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath()+ "/tempfolder/tempLoader.jsp") %>',
    data:{param1:66, param2:88},
    success:function(msg) {    
        jQuery(".loadContent").html(msg);
        jQuery("#viewpopupdiv").children().show();
    }
});
```

And my jsp:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet" prefix="portlet"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.ibm.com/jsf/html_extended" prefix="hx"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>


<div id="view"  style="text-align:left">

<table class="viewpopupdiv" style="width:480px;background-color:#efedea;border-width: thin; border-color: #ff6633; border-style:solid;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>

                            <table style="width:100%;background-color:#424341;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="editLineHeaderDarkLeft">  
                                        <span class="">Line ID</span> :&nbsp;<span class="headerValueForPopup"><%=lineDetails.getDisplayableOrderLineId()%></span></td>
                                    <td class="editLineHeaderDarkCenter">  
                                        <span class="">Order Number</span>  :&nbsp;<span class="orderNumberHeaderValueForPopup"><%=lineDetails.getDisplayableOrderHeaderId()%></span></td> 
                                    <td class="editLineHeaderDarkRight"><div href="#" onclick="closePopupForEditLine('closepopupdiv')"><img class="close" src='<%=imgURL%>' border="0"></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

<td class="editLineHeaderDarkLeft">                              
<div class="chargeTypeDropListJQ">  
                                        <h:selectOneMenu  value="#{popupBean.chargeTypeId}" styleClass="selectOneMenu">
                                            <f:selectItems value="#{popupBean.chargeType}" />
                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                                    </div>
</td>
                    </tr>  
                </table>
</td></tr></table></div>
```

Comment: just fyi. we are using jsf1.2 core framework. so i cannot even go for ajax4jsf.

Comment: richfaces 3.3 runs fine w/ jsf 1.2 so you can use a4j if you like. This isn't the answer to your question but i thought i should mention it.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Actually the client is not ready atleast for sometime to introduce any new features. so was wondering if i can get any workaround of what i am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> cannot find FacesContext

You will get this exception when you run a JSP page with JSF components as "plain vanilla" JSP without invoking the `FacesServlet`. It's the one responsible for creating the `FacesContext`. The request URL needs to match the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet` as it is been definied in `web.xml` to get all the JSF tags to run properly.

Assuming that the URL pattern is `*.jsf`, then you need to change the

```
url: '<%=renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath()+ "/tempfolder/tempLoader.jsp") %>',
```

to

```
url: '<%=renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath()+ "/tempfolder/tempLoader.jsf") %>',
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I tried doing this too what you specified above. still no luck. Actually we have the url-pattern defined as /portlet/*. like below: <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/portlet/*</url-pattern>. so i have used this to test:url: '<%=renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath()+ "/portlet/tempLoader.jsp") %>',

Comment: tempfolder is my workspace folder where the jsp is residing. i am sure the way i am accessing :url: '<%=renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath()+ "/portlet/tempLoader.jsp") %>' is not correct. Please correct me with the right url. i doubt at "/portlet/tempLoader.jsp".

Comment: I mean, it was in your original URL, but not in your new URL anymore. Shouldn't it be `/portlet/tempfolder/tempLoader.jsp`?

Comment: @BalusC: i tried keeping the /portlet/tempfolder/tempLoader.jsp but still it didnt work. Well i can see the page opening but i am not seeing the jsf tag specific components. the page has some html elements too, they are rendering properly, but when it comes to jsf no. on the console i see a null pointer exception.

Comment: I am not sure if you oversimplified the JSP code or not, but a JSF tags require a `<f:view>` root tag.

Comment: @BalusC: WOWWW... it worked. Thanks for all your help. i will write the conclusion of the solution in a few minutes.

Comment: The conclusion to this Question is: When i am trying to access the jsp through a ajax call, it will be treated as a Plan jsp with out any JSF Compliance, but in order to make it compatible with jsf you have to access it with the url pattern you specify in the web.xml and make sure you have f:view defined in the top of the jsp as a root.

Comment: This is not related to Ajax. You would have exactly the same problem when requesting the page "plain vanilla" by entering its URL in browser address bar or following a bookmark/link. It's related to basic Servlet and JSF API in general. Is it your first JSF page or something?

Comment: Yes i know it is not related to AJAX. I was trying to give a quick overview of the simple thing which i have overlooked. I am not new to JSF, i did a lot JSF. I think it is something i overlooked and it happens forgetting simple things and unless a third eye figures it out. :) may be it is something similar. Thanks for your help.